# MVC routing changes url hash when requesting partial view via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-routing, partial-views

I'm using AJAX calls to request partial views and load their html into a content area on my main Index view. I'm leveraging a hash in to the url to enable browser history support (the same way GMail url browser history works).

Everything is working fine, except after my partial view is returned and loaded, **MVC seems to be clearing everything after my url hash symbol which affects the javascript browser history stack**.

*I have a link on my main view which initiates the request*:

```
<div class="linkButton" data-bind="click:function(){Nav.makeRequest('#/MyController/Profile/2')}">Profile</div>
```

*Here's the javascript that I'm using to request and load the partial views*:

```
var Nav:function(){
    var self = this;
    $(window).bind("hashchange", self.onHashChange);

    makeRequest: function(hash){
        window.location.hash = hash;
    };

    onHashChange: function (e) {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 
        var url = 'http://localhost:3333/' + hash.substring(1);
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        });
    }
}
```

So, one of my example requests would be for: `http://localhost:3333/#/MyController/Profile/2`

The request is completed successfully and my Profile view is loaded with the correct model for the id (*2*) passed to it in the routing and the url in the browser's navigation is what is shown above.

However after the view finishes loading, the browser's url then automatically changes to this: `http://localhost:3333/#`

This doesn't affect what's currently loaded on the page, but it adds this new url to the browser's history so when I hit the 'back' button it sends the request for the partial profile view again.

*The only route I have in my Global.axax is the following*:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

I suspect that the MVC routing engine sees my request for the partial view come in (`http://localhost:3333/MyController/Profile/2`) and then matches it to the Default route which returns the url for my Index view, which of course is: `http://localhost:3333/`

I have debugged extensively on the client and the onHashChange event does indeed fire both times, once for the partial view request and then again when the url changes back to localhost:3333/# The call stack doesn't reveal any calls being made client side to cause the url to change back.

**Is there a way that I can request and load my partial view using AJAX, and hashes for history support, and have the browser's url not automatically route back to the default route path?**

Comment: I think you are mixing up what MVC does, and what your client-side script does. If MVC returns proper PartialView then routing is correct. 2nd, AJAX call itself would not change URL. Are you using some javascript library for hashing and history?

Comment: I'm not using a JS library for hashing and history, I'm only using what I listed above. So for example, I'd call my makeRequest function passing in '#/MyController/Profile/2' which would in turn cause the onHashChanged function to be called and subsequently resolve the AJAX request to 'http://localhost:3333/MyController/Profile/2'

Comment: How are you triggering the hash change? Is it from links in the page? Can you post the code for that part?

Comment: 1. You call makeRequest(), so you set proper hash. 2. AJAX call hapens. 3. When is your hash overwritten then?

Comment: As stated, it's overwritten after the partial view returns and finisihes loading

Comment: Can you post working example? This javascript snippet doesn't even work. When do you subscribe to hashchanged event? In Nav initializer? Post minimal data needed to reproduce problem.

Comment: @KodeKreachor: What about valid example? Javascript? how you initialize Nav? What is sure, your problem has nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 1):

This must what you searching for:

To manipulation with browser history you need to use new method with Html5 support

```
//use it in ur ajax function to save history 
 history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1");

//and to get ur history
     window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    something like 

$.post('url',{page:event}function(event) {
    do something
})
```

}